# Can ERC-20 tokens be used in a smart contract?

Tags: erc-20, dapps

All of the dApps I’ve seen and used so far only accept ethereum as a payment.  Is it possible for dApps (not including the token’s smart conract) to use ERC-20 tokens?

Comment: Your question needs more clarity. What exactly do payments mean here? Which type of payment? Which type of Dapps?

Answer (score 1):

Uniswap, Compound, Decentraland, all of them use ERC-20 tokens as a form of payment or for any other interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Is the payment you are talking about the transaction fee payment?
Generally the answer to your question is yes. However it's still ethereum that you need to run transactions on dApps.